# Overlapping divs in flexbox column on smaller devices

Tags: html, css, mobile, flexbox, responsive-design

I am trying to design a sidebar component for a mobile responsive web app. The goal is to have the sidebar respond to different screen sizes. However, as the screen size gets smaller, the bottom div will overlap the top div, which has a fixed height. You can see a generalized example of the issue [here](https://codepen.io/patrickl13/pen/xxVGGvz) on codepen and described in this picture. [image]

Here is a simplified snippet of the html/css from codepen

```css
.container {
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.div1 {
  height: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
 }

.div2 {
  height: 75px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
 }
```

```html
<div class='main'>
  <div class='container'> 
    <div class='div1'> 
      content div1
    </div>
    <div class='div2'> 
      content div2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What properties do you have to give (div2) to stop overlapping when it begins to encroach on div1? The desired outcome is that div2 will always be aligned vertically and the overlap with continue passed the screens current height and you would just have to scroll down to see the content of div2.

Comment: What should happen when both divs collide ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the css properties of div2 to this:

```
.div2 {
  max-height: 75px;
  height: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: lightyellow;
  border: 1px dotted black;
 }
```

The maximum height of the div2 will be 75 (so on larger screens it will be 75px, as you intended), but, as you make the screen shorter, it will start to decrease.

You can also create a media query for smaller screens.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one, replace the `height` measurement from `px` to `%` this will cause the divs to take `height` according to the height of their container the following is an example

```css
.container {
  width: 10%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.div1 {
  height: 40%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 1px dotted black;
}

.div2 {
  height: 25%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: lightyellow;
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<div class='main'>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='div1'>
      content
    </div>
    <div class='div2'>
      content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```